# create an action anytime an order is canceled

Tags: api, controllers, rest-api, order-status, admin-controller

For instance, i'm trying to send an API call when an order is cancelled.

Shouldn't this work?

```
 /**
     * Cancel order
     */
    public function cancelAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->cancel()
                    ->save();
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order has been cancelled.')
                );




                        // API Code Start   
    $data = array(
    'partner_conversion_id' =>  $order->getIncrementId(),
    'event_status' => 'decline'
    );
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://api.e.com/v3/events/approve?partner_conversion_id='.$order->getIncrementId().'&event_status=decline');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "4-1:142d244");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = ($result);
                // API Code End






            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been cancelled.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you launch this code?

Comment: This code is the whole Sales > OrderControler.php that i've moved over to local > API_Company

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not "Magento way". You need to build a custom module and solve this use observer. Use event `sales_order_save_after` and check for order state. In your case it equal to Canceled. Use something like this:

```
public function checkOrderState(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    if ($order->getState() == 'canceled') {
       /* Do your API call */
    }
}
```